# Should you import your own version of Jackson into a Flink Project?

Tags: java, jackson, apache-flink

Should you import Jackson into a Flink project separately or just use the flink-shaded version of Jackson? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the shaded Jackson with older versions of Flink is a bad idea.

We've seen failures caused by the following class loader leak:

- user decodes JSON with their user-space classes
- Jackson caches these classes internally
- this cache is in Flink's classloader if used from the shaded dependencies
- user-code class loader cannot be unloaded as long as this class is in the cache (can be quite long)
- Job restarts or session clusters will amplify this problem

This was fixed with [FLINK-29834](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-29834) in 1.16.1 and 1.17.0.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: follow David Anderson's answer

> You can perfectly use the flink-shaded version is you don't care that
> the library version will be dictated by your (possibly-changing)
> runtime.
>
> Now, the lib is shaded so feel free to supply it yourself if you want
> control of the version. There will be no compatibility issues.
>
> This being said, Jackson is a fairly stable lib and I don't think
> versions matter a lot. You can just use the flink-shaded version for
> lighter jar bundling. This also leaves you free to pick your own if
> you encounter any problem in the future.
>
> This is a non-problem to me.

Comment: See my answer for why you might care.